# openvpn adds wrong route rule

Tags: linux, networking, routing, openvpn

I setup an openvpn server. And I have one client machine. It has two interfaces

```
 +---------------------------------+                      
 |          OpenVPN client         |                    
 +-------[ ]----------------[ ]----+                        
   92.168.140.106        10.0.2.15                                                 


and OpenVpn server :

 +---------------------------------+                      
 |          OpenVPN server         |                    
 +--------------[ ]----------------+                        
          92.168.140.107
```

before the client connected to the server, the route table is:

```
default via 10.0.2.2 dev enp0s3 proto dhcp metric 101 
10.0.2.0/24 dev enp0s3 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.2.15 metric 101 
169.254.0.0/16 dev enp0s3 scope link metric 1000 
192.168.140.0/24 dev enp0s8 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.140.106 metric 100
```

after the client connected to the server.

```
default via 10.0.2.2 dev enp0s3 proto dhcp metric 101 
10.0.2.0/24 dev enp0s3 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.2.15 metric 101 
10.0.2.2 dev enp0s3 proto static scope link metric 101 
10.8.0.0/24 dev tun0 proto kernel scope link src 10.8.0.3 metric 50 
169.254.0.0/16 dev enp0s3 scope link metric 1000 
192.168.140.0/24 dev enp0s8 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.140.106 metric 100 
192.168.140.107 via 10.0.2.2 dev enp0s3 proto static metric 101
```

**As we see, a wrong rule was added :**

```
192.168.140.107 via 10.0.2.2 dev enp0s3 proto static metric 101
```

This rule causes the client can not communicate with the server.

for 192.168.140.107 , it should be via 192.168.140.1.

How to config openvpn to avoid this problem?

OS is ubuntu 18.04.6

Comment: `for 192.168.140.107 , it should be via 192.168.140.1` that's not true; the direct route `192.168.140.0/24 dev enp0s8` serves the purpose; anyway though, the problem is apparently due to the fact that openvpn assume your VPN server's remote address is covered by the original default route. Not sure if upstream is interested in / willing to address the flaw. Probably you'll have to avoid `redirect-gateway` or so (but configure the equivalent manually).